# Updating a media wiki article using Python?

Tags: python, api, cron, mediawiki

Hi
I have a cron job which collects some statistics about a service. I need the cron job to update a media wiki page (append to the page) programmatically. 
I am using python for the cron so what are my best options, are there any examples of mediawiki/python libraries or does Media wiki expose any HTTP/REST apis which I can use (may be through an extension).

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

If PyWikipediaBot is too heavy, try the Python module [mwclient](https://github.com/mwclient).

You can login, view a page’s current content, make your change and then view it in less than 10 lines [(example)](https://pastebin.com/f5ddc4945).

```
import mwclient
site = mwclient.Site('en.wikipedia.org')
site.login('Pfctdayelise','password')
page = site.Pages['User:Pfctdayelise/Test']
text = page.edit()
print text.encode('utf-8')
newtext = "\n\nTesting the write api without logging in.\n"
page.save(text+newtext,summary='testing write api')
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are running mediawiki on the same computer as the cron job, then you can use the edit.php script found in the maintanence directory.

```
/bin/python /opt/page_renderer.py | php /var/www/mediawiki/maintenance/edit.php -b PageTitle
```

In this example, `/opt/page_renderer.py` outputs wiki markdown. This gets piped to the edit script which has the `-b` flag (to mark it as a bot edit) and the title of the page you wish to edit.

Naturally, you can pipe from any program into the edit script, and you might need to change the path to the edit script if you have mediawiki installed somewhere different.

Answer (score 0):

As a committer of
https://github.com/WolfgangFahl/py-3rdparty-mediawiki
i am recommending the command line functionality of this library which allows
you to work with the markup directly from a script.

The library works best with a Semantic MediaWiki where you can query the pages your are interested in:

```sh
$ wikibackup -s orth --backupPath "/home/user/wikibackup/orth_copy" -q "[[isA::Event]]" --limit 10


downloading 10 pages from orth to /home/user/wikibackup/orth_copy

1/10 (  10%): downloading " DBKDA 2021" ...✅
2/10 (  20%): downloading "ENERGY 2021" ...✅
3/10 (  30%): downloading "ICAS 2021" ...✅
4/10 (  40%): downloading "ICNS 2021" ...✅
5/10 (  50%): downloading 2021 ICIMP ...✅
6/10 (  60%): downloading 3DUI 2020 ...✅
7/10 (  70%): downloading 3IA 2009 ...✅
8/10 (  80%): downloading 3PGIC 2010 ...✅
9/10 (  90%): downloading 4S4D 2017 ...✅
10/10 ( 100%): downloading 5GU 2017 ...✅
```

after modifying the markup you can restore the pages with:

```sh
wikirestore -t orth --backupPath "/home/user/wikibackup/orth_copy"

restoring 10 pages from /home/user/wikibackup/orth_copy to orth
1/10 (  10%): restore 2021 ICIMP ...✅
2/10 (  20%): restore "ICNS 2021" ...✅
3/10 (  30%): restore 3PGIC 2010 ...✅
4/10 (  40%): restore 4S4D 2017 ...✅
5/10 (  50%): restore "ENERGY 2021" ...✅
6/10 (  60%): restore 3DUI 2020 ...✅
7/10 (  70%): restore " DBKDA 2021" ...✅
8/10 (  80%): restore 3IA 2009 ...✅
9/10 (  90%): restore "ICAS 2021" ...✅
10/10 ( 100%): restore 5GU 2017 ...✅
```