# How to wiki POST with Python

Tags: python, http-post, wiki

Actually I have to update redirect in tons of wiki pages. In order to avoid silly work I would like to proceed by using POST requests in python.

Because wiki api is not clear for me, I would like to know how to do wiki POST request in python ? Thx in advance.

Comment: You cannot send post requests using the [Wikipedia](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/wikipedia) python package. As a user mentioned in an answer below, you will need to use something like the [Requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/) library.

Comment: Editing the wiki pages should be possible using https://github.com/mwclient/mwclient See the answer to this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4502993/updating-a-media-wiki-article-using-python

Answer (score 0):

You can read the requests library docs. It is very well explained.

http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/

```
import requests
r = requests.post('http://httpbin.org/post', data = {'key':'value'})
```